# Paramiko path specification

Tags: python, paramiko

I have the following code for a GUI that I am developing:

```
sftp = self.ssh.open_sftp()
try:
    localpath="/Users/..../signals.txt"
    remotepath = "/data1/.../sd_inputs.txt"
    sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
```

The 'localpath' is my laptop but since this is a GUI and I am developing it for users who have their own laptops/computers, is there a command in Paramiko that lets me avoid or circumvent the localpath specification, in much the same way that os.system does for python?

Comment: Okay, I am having trouble editing the block of code. How does one do that here. It came out looking terrible and incomprehensible!

Comment: What do you mean by "circumvent the localpath"? Can you give an example?

Comment: So for example in python you can write a command like this:     `os.system("SD_%s.xls" % (self.input2.GetValue()))`. Here, you don't specify the path where the "SD_" file is right? Can you do that for paramiko commands? Can you just have a command like `os.system` that can link to your system directly and you don't have to specify where the text file is to be put or gotten from?

Answer (score 0):

From your example

```
os.system("SD_%s.xls" % (self.input2.GetValue()))
```

there is nothing special about os.system here. You call self.input2.GetValue() to format a string that you pass to os.system. You can do something similar with paramiko except you have to deal with the problem that the local and remote paths are different. Assuming you have a GUI form that gives both pieces of information, it will look something like:

```
sftp.put(self.localpath.GetValue(), self.remotepath.GetValue())
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, my example wasn't meant to be anything special at all. The thing is it becomes problematic when the GUI is being used by multiple users with different localpaths, so the reason I even put the `os.system` example there was for illustrative purposes, because you don't have to specify your local path when you pass whatever `arg` into `os.system`. Some of the GUI users don't really want to be bothered with computer nomenclature etc.

Comment: @Kaysi - os.system asks the operating system to run the program and lets the OS find it using various rules. In your example, Windows finds the .xls file in the local directory and knows from its extension to run Excel with that file. You can do something similar by calling os.getcwd(). In a GUI, there use usually widgets that help the user select files and you use those values for paramiko.

Comment: Thanks so much @ tdelaney. You certainly helped as you led me to the solution I have posted here too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just discovered that I don't have to find a command in Paramiko that can circumvent or avoid the local path. Rather Python can find the local path as follows:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
localpath = path + "/signals.txt"
print localpath
```

I just have to put this stuff in the `try` block.